# Disable Jupyter Notebook automatic hyperlink

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In my notebook, I print some data from scraped web pages. Some of these are hyperlinks without tags e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com`. Unfortunately, Notebook prints these out as an actual hyperlink (i.e. wraps it in  tags) on the output page and shortens it. (So the final result in HTML looks like this: `<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">https://stacko...</a>`.) The field is set to code, but this still happens. Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**:

Enter the following text in the empty cell of your Jupyter notebook:

```
%%javascript
Jupyter.utils.autoLinkUrls = function (txt) {
    return txt;
}
```

**Explanation**:

The ability to locate URLs in text output and convert them to hyperlinks appeared in IPython notebook (a Jupyter's predecessor) as a result of a [merge request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2464) in Oct' 2012. Since then every piece of output is scanned for URLs and each found URL is replaced with an anchor `<a href=.../>`. There's no easy way to alter this behavior because function autoLinkUrls(...) doesn't provide any configuration parameters.

So, the only way to disable URL "autolinking" is to simply replace JavaScript function `autoLinkUrls`, which is exposed through global `Jupyter` object, and `%%javascript` magic command makes the job done.

Comment: THis does not work anymore, any idea how to fix it with the latest version?